# Assistance with a repeating regex expresion

Tags: regex

I know there are tons of posts and tutorials on Regex but I am stuck on something that I thought would be fairly simple, sadly not for me ...

Consider the string below:

```
DEMO1 in ( "test1", "test2", "test3"), CODE_ID in ( "test4", "test5", "test6")
```

I would like to split the line into two groups, one for 'DEMO2 in' and another for 'CODE_ID in'. The groups would ideally look like

```
Match 1 = DEMO1 in ( "test1", "test2", "test3")
Match 2 = CODE_ID in ( "test4", "test5", "test6")
```

This regex pattern gives me the gives me the 'DEMO1 in' and 'CODE_ID in' sections, problem is how to capture the rest of string up to the closing paranthesis?

```
(\w+\s+in\s)
```

How do I split and capture on the comma after the closing paranthesis. Also there could be more then just the two groups but for now just the split and capture on two sets would be very helpful.

Not sure about the lifespan of the these but here are is a regex101 the links to my current work, not much there:
https://regex101.com/r/ukwLZM/1

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat of a dirty hack, but I tested that `(\w+\s+in \([^)]\)+\))` would work.
To explain:
I capture all the symbols which are not closing parenthesis. And then also add the closing parenthesis symbol itself.

Comment: An interesting solution, however the regex tool complains about the unbalanced parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the capture group for a match only, and you can use a negated character class matching any character except the `(` and `)`

```
\w+\s+in\s+\([^()]*\)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXZz1F/1).